# How to get menu lists in redmine 3

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I have just started to develop a plugin for redmine 3.
And, I'd like to hide some menu items from the top_menu or the project menu.
I know I can use the delete_menu_item helper.
But I don't know the names of the menu items.

Is there a way to get the names of the menu items, 
maybe through "rails console" or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the [Redmine Custom CSS plugin](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_custom_css). It allows you to use custom CSS styles for your redmine. You can add a CSS style that hides the menu items. You can get the ids of the menu items using the browser developer tools. For example Chrome Developers toolbox.